# PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY error when using drush

Tags: drush

This will be less about a question and more of a way to document things. I had been attempting to use drush (Drush 11 and 12) after installing a new copy of Drupal. It kept throwing Error: Undefined Constant PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY
Yet the site worked fine. I checked php.net and Drupal Answers but to no avail. What did I need to do to get Drush working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, always make sure the PHP you are using on your web server and the php-cli are the same version. My server was running 8.1 and the cli was running 8.2. Once I changed the cli to 8.1, drush worked like a charming do-it-all tool, it is meant to be.